# Wordpress - internal server error on links after moving from local to Aruba

Tags: wordpress, mamp, local, internal-server-error, aruba

I've moved a local Wordpress website (using MAMP) on an Aruba domain. I've exported the local MySQL database using phpMyAdmin to a mydb.sql file. I've edited the file replacing all the local urls (http://localhost:8888/websitename) with the new url (http://websitename.it).

Using FileZilla I've transferred the whole content of the Wordpress website to the new domain using FTP, then I've edited the wp-config.php file changing the database name, host, username and password given from Aruba.

At this point the website is online and I can see the homepage correctly displayed.

The problem is when I click on any of the menu links, which points to other sections of the website, I got a 500 internal server error

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

If I log in to the Wordpress dashboard I can see all the website content and all the pages correctly. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can log in, go to your Permalinks settings and then click "Save" it should flush the HTaccess rules that could be causing these issues